# How to use Alamofire inside a framework?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I would like to use Alamofire in my framework's viewcontroller to make some network request.

```
// Call
let myURLString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
Alamofire.request(myURLString)
    .responseJSON { response in
        // do stuff with the JSON or error
}
```

However, it's returning

```
No such module 'Alamofire'
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add 'Alamofire' to your framework's podfile?

Comment: @EmreCiftci do I need to do pod init in my framework as well (and add alamofire to the podfile?) I've already done "pod init" and add alamofire to the main project pod file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you should create target of your CocoaTouch Framework.

And then you should add your CocoaTouch Framework to your **Main Project's PodFile:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MainApp' do
  use_frameworks!
end

target 'CocoaTouchFramework' do
  use_frameworks!
end

pod 'Alamofire'
```

Or you can set specific pods for frameworks:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

#Your custom framework's pods
def customframework_pods
    pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'MainApp' do
    pod 'MyAwesomePod', '~>1.0'
    customframework_pods
end

target 'CocoaTouchFramework' do
    customframework_pods
end
```

I found one more answer about this:

**Source:** [Youval Vaknin's Medium Article](https://medium.com/@youvalv/cocoapods-for-an-existing-multi-project-workspace-1fb73f46fede)

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!
workspace 'YourWorkSpaceName'
xcodeproj 'Project/ProjectName.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'CustomFramework/Framework.xcodeproj'

def project_pods
    pod 'Alamofire'
end

def framework_pods
    pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'ProjectName' do
    xcodeproj 'Project/ProjectName.xcodeproj'
    project_pods
end

target 'ProjectName' do
    xcodeproj 'Project/ProjectName.xcodeproj'
    project_pods
end

target 'Framework' do
    xcodeproj 'CustomFramework/Framework.xcodeproj'
    framework_pods
end

target 'Framework' do
    xcodeproj 'CustomFramework/Framework.xcodeproj'
    framework_pods
end
```

I hope it works

Enjoy

Comment: Tried to add your suggestion in the Main Project's PodFile. However getting this error: [!] Unable to find a target named `CocoaTouchFramework ` (which is my custom framework name), did find `MainApp` and `MainAppUITests`.

Comment: I'm trying to separate the Framework and the MainApp. Is there a better way to manage the cocoapods?

Comment: Hi @user1872384. Please check my edit. Take a look at the article I have shared.

Comment: Many thanks @Emri Ciftci, managed to follow your guidance. The only thing I'm missing is to create a target for my framework. Then just need to follow the steps to setup pods (only one podfile) =D